# Find vectors $u, v$ that satisfy the equation $Au = e_1$, and $Av = e_2$

Tags: matrices, vectors, cross-product

I am really new to matrices and these concepts, so any help would be much appreciated.

I have the following square matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-3&0\\1&4&-3\\0&1&5\end{bmatrix}$$

We're asked to let each row = $a_1, a_2, a_3$ going down and then calculate the cross products and triple scalar products which I was able to do.

I calculated the cross products of $a_1 \times a_3$, and then $a_2 \times a_3$: which are:

$$a_1  \times a_3 = \begin{bmatrix}-15\\-5\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ and,
$$a_2  \times a_3 = \begin{bmatrix}23\\-5\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

If $Au = e_1$ and $Av = e_2$, and I need to determine vectors $u$ and $v$, could someone explain how to find u and v. I know that if I multiply A by the cross product vectors I get $[38, 0, 0]$ and $[0, -38, 0]$ but this confuses me because I thought to satisfy the equation the answer should be $[1, 0, 0]$ and $[0,1,0]$. I have also tried finding the inverse of A and multiply this by $e_1$ and $e_2$, but the results were not even close to the result of the cross products?? I am really trying to learn, would appreciate some advice.

Is there another method to solve this??

Comment: Would be good that you rewrite your question using Latex from A to Z. Also what are $e_1,e_2$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure from context that $e_1, e_2$ are the first and second standard basis vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Your cross product strategy gives you a vector that produces *multiples* of $e_1$ and $e_2$. But remember that since $A$ is a linear transformation, $A(\lambda x) = \lambda (A x)$ for any scalar lambda and any vector $x$. So how can you choose scalars $\lambda, \mu$ so that $A(\lambda u) = e_1$ and $A(\mu v) = e_2$? (Here $u$ and $v$ are the vectors you calculated).

You were also close with the strategy of finding the inverse! Note that if the inverse has columns $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ (in that order from left to right), then
$$A A^{-1} = I = [e_1, e_2, e_3] = A [x_1, x_2, x_3] = [A x_1, A x_2, A x_3]$$
So in fact that first column of the inverse is the $u$ you're looking for, and the second column of the inverse is the $v$ you're looking for.

**EDIT:** OP asked a good question, namely whether the constants $\lambda$ and $\mu$ can be deduced without having to calculate $A u$ and $Av$ and then reverse-engineering them. And the answer is yes. We'll show it for $\lambda$, but the process is identical for $\mu$. Plugging in our expression for $u$, we notice that
$$A u = A (a_2 \times a_3) = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \cdot (a_2 \times a_3) \\ a_2 \cdot (a_2 \times a_3) \\ a_3 \cdot (a_2 \times a_3) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \cdot (a_2 \times a_3) \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
the last equality following from the properties of the triple product. So we can deduce that
$$e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \frac{(a_2 \times a_3)}{a_1 \cdot (a_2 \times a_3)}$$
And you can further note that this expression is only ill-defined (i.e. the denominator is zero) when $a_1$ is a linear combination of $a_2$ and $a_3$, which would mean that $A$ is not invertible, in which case we would have to adopt a different method to solve this problem.

Comment: Also thank you!. Does that actually mean that the lambda and mu are actually also equivalent to, or can be found, using the scalar triple products calculated earlier? The entire question then makes  beautiful sense.

Comment: @MEcho See my edits.

Answer (score 1):

**Not a complete answer, but a push in the right direction**

You have
$$A = \pmatrix{ 1&-3&0\\1&4&-3\\0&1&5}$$
You seek a vector
$$
v = \pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$$
with the property that
$$
Av = e_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}.
$$
Let's write that out:

$$
\pmatrix{ 1&-3&0\\1&4&-3\\0&1&5}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}.
$$

Doing the matrix multiplication, we get
$$
\pmatrix{ 1x-3y+0z\\1x+4y-3z\\0x+1y+5z} = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}.
$$
Without the b rackets, that's just
\begin{align}
1 &= x - 3y\\
0 &= x + 4y - 3z\\
0 &= y + 5z
\end{align}
The last equation lets you replace all $y$s with $-5z$, so we get
\begin{align}
1 &= x + 15z\\
0 &= x + 4(-5z) - 3z = x - 23z\\
0 &= y + 5z
\end{align}
From the first two, we have
$$
x = 1 - 15z; x = 23z
$$
so we conclude that
$$
23z = 1 - 15z\\
38z = 1\\
z = \frac{1}{38}
$$
From this, we can obtain $x$ and $y$ and we're done.

As you take more linear algebra, you'll learn more methodical approaches to solving problems like these, but this gets you started for now (although I may have made an algebra/arithmetic mistake or two).

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful.